# How do I solve error probkem in Kotlin Gradle plugin

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

My project is giving this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':sign_in_with_apple' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Before you block or downgrade me, it should be noted that I searched for solutions but non helped me. Below is the pictures of the versions I have.

Any help please?

[image: Flutter doctor]

[image: android buildgrader]

[image: app buildgrader]

As you can see, everything of mine is set. flutter doctor is set, versions of my plugins are higher. So what's wrong?